Why if the Hessian matrix is not zero matrix, then it has nonzero eigenvalues ? ( Anyone who have the Friedberg Linear Algebra book ; Theorem 6.37 )
I am reading the Friedberg, Linear Algebra, fourth edition, proof of Theorem 6.37 ( The Second Derivative Test ) and stuck at some statement. Let $f(t_1, t_2 ,\dots, t_n)$ be a real-valued function in $n$ real variables for which all third-order partial derivatives exist and are continuous Let $p=(p_1,p_2, \dots, p_n)$ be a critical point of $f$, and let $A(p)$ be the Hessian of $f$ at $p$ :
$$ A(p) = \frac{\partial^2f(p)}{(\partial t_i)(\partial t_j)}.$$
Note that the mixed second-order partials of $f$ at $p$ are independent of order in which they are taken. So $A(p)$ is symmetric matrix. Then my question is, if $A(p)$ is not the zero matirx, then $A(p)$ has nonzero eigenvalues? I understand this statement as "If $A(p) \neq 0$, then all eigenvalues of $A(p)$ are not zero ; equivalently, if one of eigenvalues of $A(p)$ is zero, then $A(p)=0$." Correct?
Proof of the Theorem 6.37 is as follows :





Why the underlined statement is true?

You are not interpreting the statement correctly. If $A(p) \ne 0$, not all eigenvalues are zero, i.e. there is at least one nonzero eigenvalue.

O.K. Thanks for correction.
